# endroid Qr Code in TWIG in Symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, qr-code

So I want to make a QR code dynamically by feeding it a URL in my TWIG template in Symfony. I have the endroid/QrCode bundle installed and seems to be fine, but I'm not sure how to get TWIG to create a QR code image!

So from the GitHub page, all it says for TWIG is:

> Twig extension
>
> The bundle provides a Twig extension for generating a QR code URL,
>   path or data URI. You can use the second argument of any of these
>   functions to override any defaults defined by the bundle or set via
>   your configuration.

```
<img src="{{ qrcode_path(message) }}" />
<img src="{{ qrcode_url(message, { writer: 'eps' }) }}" />
<img src="{{ qrcode_data_uri(message, { writer: 'svg', size: 150 }) }}" />
```

So I figured for a test, the easiest thing to do would be something like:

```
<img src="{{ qrcode_url('http://www.test.com') }}" />
```

However, this brings up the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route
>   "endroid_qrcode_generate" as such route does not exist.").

Anyone got the TWIG extension for this working?

Comment: You did register the bundle in `Symfony` right?

Comment: Sure did, in AppKernel.php If I didn't I don't think it would even know where to look for the function qrcode_url

Comment: Well there route is being defined in the [QrController](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode/blob/master/src/Bundle/Controller/QrCodeController.php), did you clear your cache(s) after adding the bundle?

Comment: Sure did, both dev and prod and tested both.

Comment: (The function `qrcode_ur` is a `Twig_Function` and can be found under [QrCode/src/Twig/Extension/QrCodeExtension.php](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode/blob/master/src/Twig/Extension/QrCodeExtension.php) btw)

Comment: Yeh, and its finding that function, just not the route to endroid_qrcode_generate

Comment: Works when I create the base64 string in the contoller and print it, will just do that for now, suspect there is a bug somewhere in the bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you include the route configuration for the bundle, as it is stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/endroid/QrCode#symfony-integration)

> Add the following section to your routing to be able to handle QR code URLs. This step can be skipped if you only use data URIs to display your images.

add the routing config to e.g. `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
EndroidQrCodeBundle:
    resource: "@EndroidQrCodeBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /qrcode
```

Comment: Works well, I read the documentation as the TWIG extension not requiring this part as it looks like its for the controller information. Thanks.